# CakePHP: find('count') and DISTINCT field vs. find('all') and GROUP BY field

Tags: mysql, cakephp, group-by, distinct

I am building a query in CakePHP, but cannot use a `GROUP BY` statement in my `find('count')` as it throws an error. Therefore I used instead of the `GROUP BY` statement a `DISTINCT` field in my fieldlist.

So, from `find('count', array('group' => 'field'))` I now have `find('count', array('fields' => 'DISTINCT field'))`

In another part of the application, I am using a `find('all')` to fetch the same records as above. Here, I am able to use the `GROUP BY` statement, so I have:

`find('all', array('group' => 'field'))`

My question is: are both of the queries described above returning the same results? Briefly I want to be sure that `DISTINCT field` combined with `find('count')` returns the same results as `GROUP BY field` combined with `find('all')`.

Comment: you can look at the generated sql query, and/or the data they return to determine that.

Comment: It would be a particular case. I want to be sure that this applies in general.

Comment: What error did the GROUP BY throw?

Comment: A syntax error in MySQL. Don't remember exactly as I changed it to reflect what I have asked above. I only want to be sure that the two return the same results; I believe it is not CakePHP dependent, but MySQL in general.

Answer (score 10):

An old post, but I needed help on this and eventually found the answer, so here it is.

They will be the same if you do this...

```
find('count', array('fields' => 'COUNT(DISTINCT field) as count'))
```